# put PIN on select of images

Tags: javascript

I got a page where users can select them stage in the company, and the select returns a pic of the stage.
On this one, users can put a PIN for pin their location on this stage. But i can't display the PIN on the picture select, can someone help me ??
The goal of the project is to improve the UX and easily find the desk of your friends in the company.
The problem is from the script (almost sure).

Here is my select and picture display :

```js
function showFloorPlan() {
  var selectElement = document.getElementById('floor-plan-select');
  var selectedValue = selectElement.value;
  var floorPlanImage = document.getElementById('floorPlanImage');
  var selectedFloorPlanInput = document.getElementById('selected-floor-plan');

  switch (selectedValue) {
    case '1':
      floorPlanImage.src = '/images/0.jpg';
      selectedFloorPlanInput.value = 'Val-De-Reuil Rez-de-chaussée';
      break;
    case '2':
      floorPlanImage.src = '/images/1.jpg';
      selectedFloorPlanInput.value = 'Val-De-Reuil 1er étage';
      break;
    case '3':
      floorPlanImage.src = '/images/2.jpg';
      selectedFloorPlanInput.value = 'Val-De-Reuil 2ème étage';
      break;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  showFloorPlan();
};

function initFloorPlan(elementId, imagePath, pinX, pinY) {
  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: elementId,
    width: 765.5,
    height: 287.5,
  });
  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  var floorPlanImage = new Konva.Image({
    width: 765.5,
    height: 287.5,
  });
  layer.add(floorPlanImage);

  var pinsLayer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(pinsLayer);

  var pinImageObj = new Image();
  pinImageObj.onload = function() {
    addFloorPlanImage(floorPlanImage);
  };
  pinImageObj.src = '/images/PIN.png';

  var currentPin = null;

  function addFloorPlanImage(image) {
    var floorPlanImageObj = new Image();
    floorPlanImageObj.onload = function() {
      image.image(floorPlanImageObj);
      layer.batchDraw();
    };
    floorPlanImageObj.src = imagePath;
  }

  function addPin(x, y) {
    if (currentPin) {
      currentPin.destroy();
      currentPin = null;
      pinsLayer.batchDraw();
    }

    var pin = new Konva.Image({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      image: pinImageObj,
      width: 75,
      height: 75,
      draggable: true,
    });

    pin.on('dragmove', function() {
      pinsLayer.batchDraw();
      updateHiddenFields(pin.x(), pin.y());
    });

    pinsLayer.add(pin);
    currentPin = pin;
    pinsLayer.batchDraw();

    updateHiddenFields(x, y);
  }

  function updateHiddenFields(x, y) {
    document.getElementById('pin-x').value = x;
    document.getElementById('pin-y').value = y;
  }

  floorPlanImage.on('click', function(e) {
    var pointerPos = stage.getPointerPosition();
    var offsetX = pointerPos.x - stage.getX();
    var offsetY = pointerPos.y - stage.getY();

    addPin(offsetX, offsetY);
  });

  addFloorPlanImage(floorPlanImage);

  if (pinX !== null && pinY !== null) {
    addPin(pinX, pinY);
  }
}
initFloorPlan('floorPlanImage', '/images/' + document.getElementById('floor-plan-select').value + '.jpg', {
  {
    user.pin_x
  }
}, {
  {
    user.pin_y
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="team" class="team-area">
  <form id="pin-form" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="trombi_id" value="{{ user.trombi_id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="pin-x" name="x" value="{{ user.pin_x }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="pin-y" name="y" value="{{ user.pin_y }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="selected-floor-plan" name="carte">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="site-heading text-center">
          <h2>L'équipe <span> <a href="."><img src="/Logo_AI_RVB_Couleur.png" width="40%"></a></span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <select id="floor-plan-select" onchange="showFloorPlan()">
        <option value="1" selected>Val-De-Reuil Rez-de-chaussée</option>
        <option value="2">Val-De-Reuil 1er étage</option>
        <option value="3">Val-De-Reuil 2ème étage</option>
      </select>

      <img id="floorPlanImage" alt="Plan d'étage">
    </div>

    <div class="container-localisation">
      <div class="edit-loc mt-4">
        <button class="btn btn-edit-loc">Retour</button>
        <button id="btn-modifier" class="btn btn-edit-loc" type="submit" name="save">Modifier</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives obvious console errors due to invalid JavaScript object entries. Please fix those and see if your problem is solved

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I resolve the errors but the PIN still doesn't appear.

Comment: I did NOT answer. I just created a snippet for you